# Incredibly slow Angular source map build

Tags: node.js, angular

In an effort to debug a production Angular issue, I'm trying to generate a source map for the project. As suggested on a number of SO articles I'm doing as below:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=2048
ng build --prod --sourcemaps
```

The choice of 2G RAM in the first line above is based on the fact I'm running this under VirtualBox on a laptop that I need to run other stuff on. It seems it's decided to steal a few gig of swap over and above that anyway, the HDD activity light has barely been off since the build started ...

The `ng build` process has been running for about 14 hours now, with practically that entire time having been stuck on this line:

```
69% building modules 1392/1397 modules 5 active ...b/node_modules/chartjs-color/index.js
```

This isn't a remarkably big project, how on earth is it taking this long?

I'll add that I don't really know Angular, just looking at this while the maintainer is on leave, so please don't assume I haven't missed anything obvious.

Literally all I want is the source map, not interested in anything else being built. Is there anything I can skip?

**Edit:**

I followed the one upvoted comment and tried restarting the build - same problem over and over.
Tried checking out to a fresh project and reinstalling node modules locally, as another dev suggested the fact I was checking out production atop of dev branch might be an issue - same.
Tried doubling RAM - same.

What appears to have fixed it is the addition of option `--no-aot`. But I don't know if that means it's a none-identical build, at least in terms of source map? Will find out I guess ...

Comment: It's stuck. Try running it again, this shouldn't take more than a few seconds.

Comment: Will re-try. Why would it get "stuck" sometimes and not others? There is a ticket open actually for the regular production build process hanging sometimes. All sounds a bit flaky ...